# Finite sequence created by reducing $n$ with each prime under $n$ ends in $0$?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, inequality, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

Given $n$ a fixed integer we constuct the following sequence:

$a_0=n$, $a_i=\lfloor \frac{a_{i-1}(p_i-1)}{p_i}\rfloor$. For what values of $n$ do we have $a_{\pi(n)}=0$?

Computer calculation shows it holds for all $n\in\{2,3,\dots ,10^5\}$ except $2,4,6,10,12,16,28$. Can we prove it is true for sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: Let $A_n$ be the set obtained for each $n\ge0.~$ Then its cardinals $|A_n|$ form the sequence described [here](http://oeis.org/A192512).